# Does a channel's "Generated title" take dynamic data?

Tags: channel, title

From https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/channel/tab-settings.html#generated-title

> When a new entry is created or previewed, this value will be inserted
>   by default in the Title field. This is helpful if you wish every entry
>   in a channel to have the titles follow a certain format. The automatic
>   URL Title creating javascript for the Publish page will ignore this
>   text during processing.

Anyone know if this takes dynamic data? For instance, for a channel I have first and last name. I'd like the Title to be defined as this, plus a date, not requiring my user to enter these values twice. Would I be able to have title automatically generated, like {first_name} {last_name} {entry_date}?